# Find Elements with dynamic id's and Xpaths's

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I apologize if this is a duplicate of a question already but nothing I read seemed to do the trick.

I am trying to automate the process of adding my hours for my job. This entails using selenium to mimic the process I do to enter the hours for me.

The problem is, as I navigate through the process, I have run into an instance where one of the elements has a dynamic id and xpath (any maybe other things. I am not very proficient in HTML).

[image: Problem Occurs Here]

I need to select the "Day" button on the "View" drop down. The highlighted HTML corresponds to that button. I have already checked and both the ID and Xpath change every time I create a new session. I usually do the following to find my elements:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

Below is the xpath I currently see:

```
//*[@id="ab5378a9418345a2a57ad12f066127a6"]
```

To further complicate things, the xpath for the "Week" selection is the following:

```
//*[@id="741015164c5547fbb5403c03c46636d3"]
```

I tried to figure out how to use "contains" with the xpath but even so, the two are not different enough to differentiate by using "@id". The only constant thing and difference I see each time is that the

```
 data-automation-label="Day"
```

is present on the day element and

```
data-automation-label="Week"
```

is present on the week element.

Does anyone have any experience finding the elements when a problem like such occurs? I am working in Python3.6 on a windows 7 computer.

Again, I apologize if this is a duplicate but I tried very hard to find an answer before coming here for help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use the class that is specifically in that div container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two of the below possible selectors

**XPATH**

```
//div[@data-automation-label="Day"]
```

**CSS**

```
div[data-automation-label="Day"]
```

When you use identifier your main focus should be how to find something that is unique to that object. And it really doesn't matter if it is name or id or what not. Use what you think would work the best. And here `data-automation-label` implies that itself

Comment: Yep, was just waiting until it allowed me to :)

Comment: I am now running into a very similar issue and I am hesitant to create a new thread since is corresponds with this one. I need to find another element and the consistency here is that "aria-labelledby" contains "56$187009". I tried the following but it could not find the xpath. "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@aria-labelledby, '56$187009')]")" Am I using this command correctly? I was going to DM you but could not figure out how to on SO so I apologize for the crammed/messy text

Comment: "//div[contains(@aria-labbeledby, "56$187009")]"

Comment: That's what I tried before and I got the following error: "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@aria-labbeledby, "56$187009")]"}"

Comment: Try [aria-labelledby*="uid19-formLabel"]. If that doesn't work then post a new question